# Limit of e with imaginary number

Tags: calculus

Important part:

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{-ix} - e^{-x} $

This is suppose to approximate to "$1$" but the way I see it we have $0 - 0$ ...

Comment: Are you sure there is no $\;i\;$ in the second exponential's argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the limit of a complex sequence (function) exists iff the limit of its real and imaginary parts exists:

$$e^{-ix}-e^{-x}=\cos x-e^{-x}-i\sin x\;,\;\;\text{and since}\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$$

doesn't exist the original limit doesn't, either.

**Added:** If you wanted instead

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}|e^{-ix}-e^{-x}|=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\cos^2x-2e^{-x}\cos x+e^{-2x}+\sin^2x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{1-2e^{-2x}\cos x+e^{-2x}}=\sqrt{1-0+0}=1$$

Comment: What if we square the original expression?

Comment: I don't think that'll help...

Comment: @rumblerumble That won't help, but perhaps you want to take the *complex norm* of the expression...?

Answer (score 1):

Expand the term with the imaginary exponent using Euler's formula:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left[e^{-ix} - e^{-x}\right] = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left[\cos(-x) + i\sin(-x) - e^{-x}\right]=\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(x) - i\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)$$

which does not converge to either 0 or 1, but instead oscillates around the unit circle.